# Running deceleration after instant force

Tags: momentum, velocity

Given a person can run at 10 metres per second. If they are moved to 100 metres per second with an instant force, I'm trying to understand 3 cases of movement.

Case 1, the person doesn't apply any force themselves and slows down from 100 metres per second with drag and friction.
Case 2, the person tries running in the same direction as the instant force, eventually reaching their running speed of 10 metres per second.
Case 3 the person tries running in the opposite direction of the instant force, slowing to a stop.

I have case 1 working in a Unity project, but I don't understand the other cases. How can I factor their running into the deceleration?

Comment: Person maximum force (and deceleration) and person maximum speed are different quantities. They do not link with each other.